# Cannot Create Legend in R for Simple Scatterplot: Will not accept legend=c("name", "name")

Tags: r, legend

Can someone PLEASE help me figure out why I can't create a legend in R? I have been trying for DAYS. Googling and watching videos. And I KNOW this code works for other people, but not for me. I am using a CSV file. Cannot use TXT file, it won't import correctly. (I have a Mac OS)

It keeps saying

> "Error in as.graphicsAnnot(legend) : argument "legend" is missing, with no default"

I have tried numerous things. I just want the colors to be represented for treatment and control. (green=treatment, black=control). The shape is `pch=19` (filled in circles). It obviously has an error with the `legend=c("Treatment", "Control")` but I have no clue why.

This is my code for the whole plot:

```
plot(DEPTH, FISH, main="Fish < 3cm vs. Depth", xlab="Depth", ylab="Fish >3cm CPUE ", pch=19, abline(lm(FISH~DEPTH), col="black"), col=ifelse(CSV_Fish_3_vs_Depth_Minnow$SEP== 2, "green", "black"), legend(20,35), legend=c("Treatment","Control"), col=c("green", "black"), pch=19:19, cex=.8, box.col="darkgreen")
```

This is my code for the legend (the part that's not working):

```
legend(20,35), legend=c("Treatment","Control"), col=c("green", "black"), pch=19:19, cex=.8, box.col="darkgreen")
```

My data is below. Very Simple. The SEP column is to separate the Treatment and Control in the `ifelse` argument. No clue why it won't accept it:

```
MACHOL  DEPTH   FISH    SEP
M1E     59      4.5      1
M1W     45      5.5      1
M2E     42      5.25     2
M2W     25      1.5      2
M3E     20      2.25     2
M3W     43      8.75     2
M4E     35      1.25     1
M4W     30      0.5      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use legend() as a function, not within plot().

Try this:

```
plot(...)   #plot your data

legend("left", c("Treatment", "Control"), 
       col = c("green", "black"),
       pch = c(19, 19), cex = 0.8, 
       box.col = "darkgreen"
       )
```

Comment: Ok I did try to do it separate from the plot function before as well and it didn't do anything. I am wondering what the "df" is for? I am new to R and trying to figure all this out. Is it just to make a short cut for the name of the file?

Comment: I think you are reffering to timfaber's post. He saved the dataframe in the variable "df". With the $-operator you can select the columns of the dataframe by name. This is actually really usefull. Like this: dataframe$column

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df = read.table(text="
MACHOL DEPTH FISH SEP 
M1E 59 4.5 1 
M1W 45 5.5 1 
M2E 42 5.25 2 
M2W 25 1.5 2 
M3E 20 2.25 2 
M3W 43 8.75 2 
M4E 35 1.25 1 
M4W 30 0.5 1",header=T)

plot(df$DEPTH, df$FISH, main="Fish < 3cm vs. Depth", xlab="Depth",
 ylab="Fish >3cm CPUE ", pch=19, abline(lm(df$FISH~df$DEPTH), col="black"), 
 col=ifelse(df$SEP== 2, "green", "black")) 

legend(30,8,legend=c("Treatment","Control"), col=c("green", "black"), pch=19, cex=.8, box.col="darkgreen")
```

Comment: I get this: Error in df$DEPTH : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: No wait sorry. IT worked, except the # made my regression line not show up

Comment: Removed the hashtag and it worked! So what it the difference here?